# Language-selector-common in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, dpkg

When I am trying to install various packages, for example gitk and ruby1.8-dev, I recieve the following output:

`Setting up language-selector-common (0.6.7) ...

dpkg: error processing language-selector-common (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector:

 language-selector depends on language-selector-common (= 0.6.7); however:

  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing language-selector (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Processing triggers for python-central ...

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a   previous failure.

                          Errors were encountered while processing:

 language-selector-common

 language-selector

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I have tried forcing the dependencies, and deleting the entries in the var/lib/dpkg/status and many more things, that all failed.

I am running this on a VM on Virtual Box, if that helps any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with installing `language-selector-common` version 0.6.7. The new version (0.6.8) is already up. I think you should be able to just `sudo apt-get update` and reinstall your gitk and ruby.

You can see the related bug reports here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-selector/+bug/766412
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-selector/+bug/766534

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit a file for post installation:

```
sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.postinst
```

Look for this line:

```
kill $(pgrep -U root '^ls-dbus-backend$') 2>/dev/null
```

append || true so that its look like:

```
kill $(pgrep -U root '^ls-dbus-backend$') 2>/dev/null || true
```

then run:

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```